# After Migrating my site magento1 to magento2 On product detail page images display wrong

Tags: magento2, gallery-image

After migrating My site magento1 to magento2 on product detail page images display with watermark.

How can i display original small images?

**Original image:**(magento1)

[image]

**Magento2 images after migration:**

[image]

Comment: can you explain me which steps i have to follow for do migration in mangeto 2 ?

Comment: Are you asking for my question solution or general?

Comment: No its general asking

Comment: Ask question in stack exchange with which info you want for migration. i will reply over there @RvSingh

Comment: I know that but you know so please share this

Comment: Wanna I ask to stack